# Delete last occurrence of a variable using sed / bash script

Tags: sed

I have multiple files written as */*/*/*/ ... */*.h or .hpp. I need to get the directories of these files, instead of the files themselves. Is there any way, using sed, I could do something like 'find last / in line, then delete whatever comes next until \n?\

PS: I know about \(.*\) or (.*) and then referring to the ith occurrence as \i, but is there a way I can tell sed to delete \i?\

Edit:
I produced a file from doing something like

```
find . | grep *.h >> file ; find . | grep *.hpp >> file
```

and what I am trying to process are the contents of this file.

Comment: So - you want to remove a trailing sequence of non-`/` characters? similar to the `dirname` command, or the POSIX shell expansion `${var%/*}`?

Comment: Sorry @steeldriver, I was missing some information. The post is now edited.

Comment: Well that seems like an awfully roundabout way of doing it - at least with GNU find, you could do something like `find . \( -name '*.h' -o -name '*.hpp' \) -printf '%h\n'`. At the very least, you don't need both `find` and `grep` AND `sed` here.

Comment: Well I was just simplifying what I did. This has to do with a bash script that takes project versions from a file, then parses this `find .` with the correct OS, architecture, and version I am trying to use. The *.h *.hpp written in this 'file' are about a couple hundred out of a couple thousand.
The final step would be to delete all repeated lines, change all newlines for spaces and add a -I in front of each to just hand one variable to the compiler and have all include directories specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the directories that contain files with filename suffixes `.h` or `.hpp` using `find`:

```bsh
find . -type f \( -name '*.h' -o -name '*.hpp' \) -exec dirname {} \;
```

This finds the pathnames of all regular files whose names match one of the two given patterns.  For each such pathname, the `dirname` utility is used to extract the directory path portion of the pathname.

With GNU `find`, you could instead do

```bsh
find . -type f \( -name '*.h' -o -name '*.hpp' \) -printf '%h\n'
```

This uses the non-standard `-printf` to print the "head" of the pathname (i.e., the directory path) with the `%h` formatting option.

To get unique pathnames, you could switch to looking for directories instead of files:

```bsh
find . -type d -exec bash -O nullglob -O dotglob -c '
    for pathname do
        set -- "$pathname"/*.{h,hpp}
        [[ $# -ne 0 ]] && printf "%s\n" "$pathname"
    done' bash {} +
```

This runs a short `bash` script for batches of pathnames of directories.  The short script is run with the `nullglob` and `dotglob` shell options enabled, meaning globbing patterns that don't match anything are removed and that globbing patterns may also match hidden names.

The loop iterates over the current batch of pathnames and expands the two globbing patterns `*.h` and `*.hpp` in each directory.  If the patterns match at least one name, the directory's pathname is outputted.

This last variation would however report directories that contain files of any type matching the names `*.h` or `*.hpp`, not just regular files.

---

In the `zsh` shell:

```bsh
typeset -U dirs=(./**/*.(h|hpp)(.ND:h))
print -r -C1 $dirs
```

This creates an array variable, `dirs`, that will only store unique elements.  We initialize it to the set of directories anywhere beneath the current directory containing regular files matching `*.h` or `*.hpp`, and then we print the contents of the array.

Comment: `find ... | sort -u` might be shorter for removing duplicates (bar issues with names containing newlines etc.)

Comment: @ilkkachu and to deal with newlines in filenames, GNU `find ... -printf '%h\0 | sort -z -u` will work.  populate an array with the dirs using bash's `readarray`/`mapfile`.